# HLSL fragment shader different color for every vertex?

Tags: shader, hlsl, fragment-shader

can i make different colors for every vertex instance of this shader? do i have to send instance to o.output to the frag color? It's the Unity3d implementation of HLSL running *Graphics.DrawProcedural (MeshTopology.LineStrip);*

```
        #pragma fragment frag
        #include "UnityCG.cginc"

                StructuredBuffer<float3> buf_Points;
                StructuredBuffer<float3> buf_Positions;

                struct ps_input {
                    float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
                };

                ps_input vert (uint id : SV_VertexID, uint inst : SV_InstanceID)
                {
                    ps_input o;
                    float3 worldPos = buf_Points[id] + buf_Positions[inst];
                    o.pos = mul (UNITY_MATRIX_VP, float4(worldPos,1.0f));
                    return o;
                }

                float4 frag (ps_input i) : COLOR
                {
                    return float4(1,0,0,1); 
                }

                ENDCG
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, it's something of this kind:

```
        struct ps_input {
            float4 pos : SV_POSITION ;
            float4 col : COLOR;
        };

        ps_input vert (uint id : SV_VertexID, uint inst : SV_InstanceID)
        {
             bla 

            o.pos = mul (UNITY_MATRIX_VP, float4(worldPos,1.0f));
            o.col = float4(sin(inst),0,0,1);
            return o;
        }

        float4 frag (ps_input i) : COLOR
        {
            return i.col;//float4(0.7f,.7f,.7f,1);
        }

        ENDCG
```